# Java - Returning integer values from switch statements

Tags: switch-statement, return

```
public class CS1702_Lab8 
{
public static void DaysInAMonth()
{
    int daysinmonth = 0;
    int days = Month(daysinmonth);
    System.out.println(days);
}
public static int Month(int daysinmonth)
{
    String month = "September";
    switch(month)
    {
        case "January": 
            daysinmonth = 31;
            break;
        case "February":
            daysinmonth = 28;
            break;
        case "March":
            daysinmonth = 31;
            break;
        case "April":
            daysinmonth = 30;
            break;
        case "May":
            daysinmonth = 31;
            break;
        case "June":
            daysinmonth = 30;
            break;
        case "July":
            daysinmonth = 31;
            break;
        case "August":
            daysinmonth = 31;
            break;
        case "September":
            daysinmonth = 30;
            break;
        case "October":
            daysinmonth = 31;
            break;
        case "November":
            daysinmonth = 30;
            break;
        case "December":
            daysinmonth = 31;
            break;
        default: 
            daysinmonth = -1;
            break;
    }
      return daysinmonth;
}
}
```

Can someone tell me why nothing is printing please? I am using a switch statement in my month method and want to return the daysinmonth integer values to public static void DaysInAMonth. Im a beginner at Java so I apologise in advance for any basic errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple use `static void main(String[] args)` instead of DaysInAMonth().
So the whole change would only be:

```
public static void DaysInAMonth()
{
    int daysinmonth = 0;
    int days = Month(daysinmonth);
    System.out.println(days);
}
```

to

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int daysinmonth = 0;
    int days = Month(daysinmonth);
    System.out.println(days);
}
```

**Why?**
Simply because every program needs a starting point. Without any main method in your class the program won't even be started.

Comment: wow haha, It's funny cause I already created a main method (I forgot to copy and paste it because I was in a rush) but I noticed that I hadn't initialised the submethod DaysInAMonth() in the main method! 
Silly mistake, appreciate the help thank you.